# Jenkins- Display link to build output- residing on shared path (outside workspace)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

Hell All, I have a job/build configured in jenkins that does the entire build from a local copy (not a version controlled one at this moment). As part of the build process, some files/pre-generated reports are copied into a shared drive (located in the production machine) as build output.

Is there a way i can display the path to the build output in the Jenkins dashboard for that particular build. ArtifactDeployer does not seem to help and i'm not much familiar with it as well. Any suggestions would help me a lot to accomplish this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure of a native way of achieving this but you could achieve something similiar by writing code to invoke the Jenkins API to update the description for a particular build number with relevant information (such as build output path) that cannot be accessed through Jenkins itself.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I did explore description setter to meet my need and i'm having some difficulties in getting it done. One update to my actual post is that Jenkins can access the path where i copy the build output. Because, i have a copy task defined in the job that does the copy of binaries to the shared drive.

Comment: I believe I had also ran into troubles with that plugin trying to achieve something similiar. I had ultimately ended up writing code myself to update the job description through the Jenkins API. This had worked out smoothly for me since I had more control over what the code was doing, albeit a bit overkill for what should be a simple task.

Comment: do you have the path in a build parameter? perhaps you can use the groovy post build like this: summary = manager.createSummary("folder.gif")
summary.appendText("The path is ${PATH_VARIABLE}", false)